# Qrcode scanner nonstop scanning

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

In my app, QR code scanner functions as intent to next page.
Now the problem is whenever a QR code appears in front of my camera, it will keep scanning and open many many same pages. ( sry, my English is not good, hope u guys can understand the situation).

I wish it only scan one time and only open one page for me.

here is my code:

```
barcodeDetector.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {
    @Override
    public void release() {

    }

    @Override
    public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
        final SparseArray<Barcode> qrcodes = detections.getDetectedItems();
        if(qrcodes.size() != 0)
        {
            txtResult.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //Create vibrate
                    Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                    vibrator.vibrate(1000);
                    txtResult.setText(qrcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(User.this,Menu.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Can anyone help me to fix it?

Comment: @user1506104 , so all i need to do is just add stop(); inside the receiveDetection?

Comment: @user1506104, i tried, there is no stop(); stuff

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop scanning and store data from Google's Vision API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32558923/how-to-stop-scanning-and-store-data-from-googles-vision-api)

Answer (score 0):

After

```
txtResult.setText(qrcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue);
```

add the following:

```
cameraPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
cameraSource.stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

After opening new activity than just finish the current activity. Like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(User.this,Menu.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Hope this will help.